# Python2.7 in Conda Env not found in Registry

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, anaconda, conda

I'm working on Windows 10 and I have just installed python 2.7 in a Conda Environment with the cmd command `conda create -n python27 python=2.7 anaconda`.
This worked fine and now I have a python 2.7 installed in C:\Anaconda3\envs\python27 which I can activate and deactivate when needed.
The problem is that I'm also trying to get a python code (for python 2.7) included in a Windows Installer which is only recognizing (*i.e.* finding in registry) the "principal" python version I have installed (it's a python 3.5 installed in C:\Anaconda3) and not the python 2.7 I would need.
How can I solve my problem? Is there some Conda trick I can easily use?

Thanks!